# VB.Net Datatable Loop Suggestion

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a datatable whose query is grouped hence all my records and the immediate next record have contain related record. however there are instances when the next record may not be related to the preceeding one.

My scenario:

The data contains two related record where the first has the user time-in date and time and the next record contain the user time-out date and time.

My assignment is to detect the user time-in and time-out and process further.

I am wondering what is the best way to do this.

here is my current code.

```
Dim i as Integer = 0

For Each ucdr in ucdt.Rows
if ucdr(i) = ucdr(i+1) Then
'Do something 
End If
Next
```

However 'i' will always change in the loop, so I am wondering how to  best fix this loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as i have understood you want to know if this row's `UserTimeIn` column contains the same value as the next row's `UserTimeOut` column.

You have to use a `For`-loop to access rows via row-index:

```
For i As Int32 = 0 To ucdt.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim thisRow = ucdt.Rows(i)
    Dim nextRow = If(i = ucdt.Rows.Count - 1, Nothing, ucdt.Rows(i + 1))
    If nextRow IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim userTimeIn = thisRow.Field(Of Date)("UserTimeIn")
        Dim userTimeOut = nextRow.Field(Of Date)("UserTimeOut")
        If userTimeIn = userTimeOut Then
            ' do whatever you need to do '
        End If
    End If
Next
```